# AppLinkData.CompletionHandler never resets

Tags: android, fbsdkappinvitecontent

I'm using FB AppInvite with a deep link. When I press the "Open" from the invite I get the deep link correctly.

The problem is that once I do that, all subsequent activations of the app are activating the onDeferredAppLinkDataFetched() callback with the same deep-link. It doesn't matter if I launch the app from the launcher or from the overview screen.

Here is the code:

```
if (targetUrl != null) {
  Log.d(TAG, "App Link Target URL: " + targetUrl.toString());
  processReferral(targetUrl.toString());
} else {
  AppLinkData.fetchDeferredAppLinkData(
      activity,
      new AppLinkData.CompletionHandler() {
        @Override
        public void onDeferredAppLinkDataFetched(AppLinkData appLinkData) {
          String deeplink = appLinkData.getTargetUri().toString();
          Log.w(TAG, "Deferred App Link Target URL: " + deeplink);
          // This is happening too aggresively - every activation after one acceptance
          processReferral(deeplink);
        }
      });
}
```

Will appreciate any clue :-)

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this?

Comment: I just added a flag in SharedPreferences and am checking it before calling fetchDeferredAppLinkData..